# Formula to factor $ax^3 - x + b^2 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, factoring

Hello I have a polynomial of the form $ax^3 - x + b^2$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Does anyone know if there is a nice formula to factor this polynomial by any chance?
Thank you very much!

Comment: This is equivalent to solve an equation of degree 3. There are no easy factorization.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Derivation_of_the_roots, the depressed cubic